# In what sense is a Donut isomorphic to a Mug?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am studying a bit of Topology and I am utterly confused when trying to figure out  what sense people say that stuff like "A donut is isomorphic to a cup".

What topology (open set definition) are we putting on donut? Is it the induced topology from the ambient space? If so, does it mean we necessarily need ambient space to talk about these things like "topological invariants"?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451472/coordinate-patches-attached-to-a-2-manifold

Answer (score 4):

When we say sentences such as "a donut is homeomorphic to a cup" it is understood that those objects have the usual topology, that is their topology as objects in the "real world" (or some mathematical version of it), which is as you surmised their topology induced by the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

It is not in general necessary to have an ambient space to talk about topology or topological invariants: indeed, the definition of a topological space is perfectly intrinsic, with no reference to any bigger space. But if you want to talk about a shape or object which is familiar from everyday life, it is natural that the topology is inherited from euclidean space.

Comment: I am still confused, so all this euler characteristic, genus etc are for only the inherited topologies? Is it iimpossible to write the topology of a surface without doing it through the ambient space?

Comment: No, not at all, as I said, pretty much all topological notions are intrinsic and do not depend on an ambient space. This is the case in particular for the Euler characteristic and the genus of a surface. But if you want to draw pictures and have an geometric intuition of what is going on, it can be useful to work inside a familiar space such as a euclidean space.

Comment: I am confused, Does it not make sense to imagine a torus (with it's shape) without the ambient space?

Comment: Well, take a usual torus, and forget about the ambient space. Just remember the underlying set of the torus itself, and the set of all its open subsets. That defines a topological space, which is a torus. There are other ways to build tori without going through an ambient space: for instance you can start with a square, and glue together opposite edges (topologically speaking this mean taking some quotient of the square). As a topological space, this is homeomorphic to the usual torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Okay, I think you have clarified the most. I have upvoted your answer but I think there is more to understand before I can accept any one of the answers posted..

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but the [top mani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) and [diff mani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition) definitions same in wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing both as compact manifolds in for example $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual topology $T_u$ they are **homeomorphic**since both of them has the same genus $g=1$ (number of holes) . That's because we Can deform one in another with transformations that respect the invariants between them

Comment: Why do you use the word' manifold'? Does it not suffice to do it at toplogical leveL?

Comment: Sorry im not native and don't Know how to call them exactly. In my country we use the same words for different things. Anyways i mean that they are two connected orientable surfaces

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational There is a notion of topological manifold, which is, as its name implies, purely topological. Though it is true that usually when the word "manifold" is used alone, it refers to differential manifolds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a little bit more insight on how it actually looks like. Suppose we have a surface $S$ resting in space like so:

[image]

Suppose we were to take a point in the surface, consider an open ball centered at it , it would be highlighted like so (the boundary is light because open set don't have boundary):

[image]

The intersection would give a curved patch of points like so:

[image]

And these type of curved patches are the open sets of the topology.